# VBA to update SQL Server 2014 database table

Tags: string, vba, connection, sql-server-2014

I am getting an error when this code attempts to execute the function `GetinsertText`:

> Run-Time '-214721900 (80040e14)': [Microsoft][ODBC  SQL Server Driver]
>   [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near the keyword "open"

I am using the Microsoft ActiveX data object 6.1 as my reference. Is it my type of data I am passing which is decimal and dates?

```
Option Explicit
Const SQLConSTR As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Test;Initial Catalog=Test1;User ID=TestTest;Password=Test123;"
  Sub HITBTC_Ticker_DB_Update()
  Dim HITBTCupdate As ADODB.Connection
  Dim HITBTCcmd As ADODB.Command
  Set HITBTCupdate = New ADODB.Connection
  Set HITBTCcmd = New ADODB.Command
  HITBTCupdate.ConnectionString = SQLConStr
  HITBTCupdate.Open
  HITBTCcmd.ActiveConnection = HITBTCupdate
  HITBTCcmd.CommandText = GetinsertText
  HITBTCcmd.Execute
  HITBTCupdate.Close
  Set HITBTCupdate = Nothing
End Sub


Function GetinsertText() As String
  Dim SQLstr As String
  SQLstr = "INSERT INTO tblBCNBTC(" & _
  "[Column1.ask], [Column1.bid], [Column1.last], [Column1.open],Column1.low],[Column1.high], [Column1.volume], [Column1.volumeQuote], [Column1.timestamp],[Column1.symbol])" & " Values(" & _
  "'0.0000005939', '0.0000005904', '0.0000005922', '0.0000005800','0.0000005686', '0.0000006000','833783600','485.83049356','2018-01-26T01:17:08.060Z','BCNBTC')"
  GetinsertText = SQLstr
End Function
```

[DB update success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOVQL.jpg)

Comment: This is your third question here in the past 45 days, and you've made absolutely no effort to format any of them. Please at least try to learn, so we're not having to clean up the mess for you every time. Please [edit] your post, and then click the little **?** toolbar button to get help with proper formatting. Thanks.

Comment: @braX: How is this poster ever going to learn to format code if everyone keeps rushing in to do it for them?

Comment: @braX: The poster should be responsible for properly asking the question, and that includes formatting code.

Comment: @The individuals with the negative comments and approaches to teaching someone, Thank you for passive aggressive criticism but there are other methods to approach someone who evidently has a learning curve and a culture to get exposed to and understand. I do appreciate all the help i have received at this site but really, explain the intent with constructive criticism and don't humiliate or attempt to belittle someone.

Comment: @Xango you need to carefully check your single quotes in your `Values` part - I see at least 2 mistakes. and keep in mind that only strings need single quotes, numbers cannot use them at all.

Comment: last, open, timestamp are reserved words in SQL Server, you should contain these columns with brackets like this [Column1.last], [Column1.open], [Column1.timestamp]

Comment: I made some changes as suggested. I checked my single quotations and added the brackets to my columns identification. I also changed my connection string drivers. in the image i see my decimals did not update. This will be my next research effort. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use square brackets for your column names. Also, a *quote* seems to be missing at the end of your SQL statement. See the revised SQL below:

```
  SQLstr = "INSERT INTO tblBCNBTC(" & _
 "[Column1.ask], [Column1.bid], [Column1.last], [Column1.open], [Column1.low], 
 [Column1.high], [Column1.volume], [Column1.volumeQuote], [Column1.timestamp], 
 [Column1.symbol])" & " Values(" & _
 "0.0000005939', '0.0000005904', '0.0000005922', '0.0000005800', 
 '0.0000005686', '0.0000006000','833783600','485.83049356','2018-01-
 26T01:17:08.060Z','BCNBTC')"
```